# Kolmogorov–Smirnov TOST based on confidence bands

Tags: confidence-interval, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, equivalence, tost

I am trying to setup a two one-sided test (TOST) version of the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test (KS) based on [confidence bands](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/324/).
I would like to know if there is anything wrong with my approach.

Similar to the TOST approach to [test for equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test), where one basically checks if the confidence interval is completely inside the delta margins,
I want to test for equivalence of distributions using the Kolmogorow-Smirnow test (KS) by checking if the confidence band is completely inside the delta band.

I want to test if some distribution $f_X$ with $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X$ is close to a normal distribution $N(0, \sigma_X)$ within some $\Delta$ margin by checking if the KS confidence band is completely inside the chosen $\Delta$ band (see image).

[image]

The confidence band is defined around the empirical CDF $S_X(x)$ of the distribution $f_X$, as $S_X(x) \pm d_\alpha$, where $d_\alpha = {\sqrt{-0.5 \ln\left(\alpha \over 2\right)} \over \sqrt{n}}$ is the approximation of the [KS critical value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) for $n > 35$ divided by the square root of the sample count $n$.

My main question is, how should I define or choose the extent of the $\Delta$ band?
Currently, I define the $\Delta$ band as follows:

I choose some mean difference threshold $\delta_x$ and use it to shift $N(0, \sigma_X)$ by $\delta_x$ to $N(\delta_x, \sigma_X)$ and compute the maximum value difference $\delta_y$ between both CDFs:

$\delta_y = \left|N(0, \sigma_X)({\delta_x \over 2}) - N(\delta_x, \sigma_X)({\delta_x \over 2})\right|$.

This difference $\delta_y$ is the extent of the delta band:

$CDF_{N(0, \sigma_X)}(x) \pm \delta_y$

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this approach or if I should define $\delta_y$ differently.